# youtube-dl not working since Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade

Tags: python, 16.04, youtube-dl

I recently updated my ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 and since then `youtube-dl` does not work. I get the following error

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/v=KV2ssT8lzj8
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl", line 7, in <module>
      from youtube_dl import main
    ImportError: No module named 'youtube_dl'
```

Comment: Try `youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KV2ssT8lzj8`

Comment: @DKBose still the same error persists

Comment: Try installing `youtube-dl` again: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall youtube-dl`

Comment: @BharadwajRaju same error even after reinstalling

Comment: try `sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl`

Comment: @nicandris thanks it worked. you should post it as an answer. is it an issue with the ubuntu packages? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl`. If a module is missing this is how you install it (in this case upgrade/reinstall)

Answer (score 5):

Many users on similar QA all had problems because they didn't follow the official installation instructions.

If you used **apt-get**, remove the old version like this :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge youtube-dl
```

Install the new one by using these commands :

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Try again  : `youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KV2ssT8lzj8`

[source](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#installation)

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 reached end of life on January 1st, 2020.

If you installed `youtube-dl` using pip, uninstall with pip...:

```
sudo pip uninstall youtube_dl
```

*(Note the `_` in `youtube_dl`. Skip this to retain the old version.)*

---

The other option is to keep the old one, and install it again with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

If you do it this way, the path will be under `/usb/bin`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try reinstalling youtube-dl ? 
And after reinstalling try this command

```
youtube-dl -cit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50VWOBi0VFs
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes i did still the error persists. here is what i did`sudo apt-get purge youtube-dl` followed by `sudo apt-get update` then installed it using `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` and finally did `youtube-dl --update` sadly the same error :(

Comment: Remove it and install it directly from their website
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2016.05.10/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl